# Unity - Failed to compile resources with the following parameters:

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I'm working on adding Google Play Game Services to a Unity project.

Started getting these errors recently, however not sure if it is because of the Game Services, or could be I updated my machine.

The following in Console output:

> Failed to compile resources with the following parameters:
>   -bootclasspath "/Users/alex/development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platforms/android-21/android.jar"
>   -d "/Users/alex/Documents/development/unity/Maze/Maze/Temp/StagingArea/bin/classes"
>   -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -encoding UTF-8 "com/facebook/android/R.java" "com/google/android/gms/R.java"
>   "com/google/example/games/basegameutils/R.java"
>   "com/google/example/games/mainlibproj/R.java"
>   "com/mildspring/maze/R.java" warning:
>   java/lang/Object.class(java/lang:Object.class): major version 51 is
>   newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
>   It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded. 1 warning
>
> UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

---

> Error building Player: UnityException: Resource compilation failed!
>   Failed to recompile android resource files. See the Console for
>   details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got my answer, the issue was that "major version 51" is java 1.7, "version 50" is java 1.6.  The solution was to install Java 1.7 and set path accordingly with the following command.

```
sudo ln -nsf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me but I did one more step of copying `zipalign exec` file from folder build-tools/19.1.0 and pasting into tools folder to avoid error - `Error building Player: Win32Exception:`

Comment: Great. Works for me. OS X 10.10, Unity 4.6.0, Android API 20, java version 1.8.0_25

Comment: Worked for me, had to upgrade JDK 1.7 to 1.8... Had the same error.

Answer (score 0):

For me, changing the JDK path at `Preferences => External Tools => JDK` finally resolved this issue. Creating the symbolic link wasn't enough or possibly not even needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would just **re-install or update JDK** , And its **work**

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: JSK <- typo for JDK ? or such thing exist ?

Comment: @Lego Opps sorry